# How to say "buy a fresh one"

Tags: word-usage, pronoun

I am trying to say the sentence "This apple is not fresh, but I can buy a fresh one."  Here is my attempt based on pure translation:

> Der Apfel ist nicht frisch, aber ich kann einen frischen einen kaufen.

I know *ein* can be used with *der/die/das* to signify "the one", so I have tried to extend the logic to cover "a fresh one".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close, but correct would be

> Der Apfel ist nicht frisch, aber ich kann einen frischen kaufen.

In German, other as in English, you have kind of an implicit reference: "einen frischen [missing noun]" means: look in the context before<sup>(*)</sup> for a noun that would fit in here. Phrases were this lookup is not unambigious will/should be usually avoided.

<sup>(*)</sup>@Em1 correctly pointed out that forward references, where the missing noun will be provided in the context that follows, are possible, too:

> Ich kann einen frischen kaufen, wenn du den Apfel nicht magst.

IMHO these cases are much rarer, but I can't prove that.

Answer (score 1):

> Der Apfel ist nicht frisch, aber einen frischen kann ich ja kaufen.

Well I don't think your translation is wrong except for the repeated "einen".

Comment: The second part of your sentence has an "unusual" word order.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is almost correct. You should say :

> Der Apfel ist nicht frisch, aber ich kann einen frischen kaufen.

To say " the one" in German is das/die/ der eine. For example:

> Die Frau ist schön. - Welche? Die eine in der Mitte des Zimmers.

To say " a good one" is  einer, eine, eines and it reflects the gender of the noun.

> Mein Computer ist  abgestürtzt! Ich werde mir einen neuen kaufen.

Comment: "Die eine" sounds like "the only one" in this context. I would translate "the one" with just "die", so that the whole sentence becomes "Die in der Mitte des Zimmers".